# Why can't Windows find the issuer of my certificate?

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, code-signing, digital-certificate

I'm trying to code-sign my Windows app (built on a Mac with Unity) for the first time.  I've used osslsigncode with my private key and a developer certificate issued by Apple (which I realize is unusual, but I don't see why it shouldn't work).

The resulting executable is clearly signed, but it still throws the scary "Unknown Publisher" warning when the user launches it.  Digging into the file properties shows a signature, but says "The certificate in the signature cannot be verified".  It correctly lists the issuer as "US, Apple Inc., Apple Certification Authority".  But when I get details on the certificate, it says "Windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate."

Now, there are buttons at this point for "Install Certificate..." and "Issuer Statement", which I suspect would satisfy it, but of course I can't expect my end-users to do that.

So, what exactly is missing here?  Are there only certain CAs that will work with out complaint, and if so, where can I find that list?  Or is there something else missing in my app?

Note: if more details are needed, screenshots of all the certificate dialogs are posted [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/sign-build-windows-installer-from-a-mac.352107/).

Answer (score 2):

It lists *US, Apple Inc., Apple Certification Authority* which is the **CA** (Certificate Authority - which is also represented by a certificate) that was used to sign the certificate, or better to issue the certificate, because that info is in the certificate itself.

You can see the CA as a parent of your certificate.

Now, the reason why Windows can't verify your certificate is because it doesn't know anything about the cert's **parent CA**.

To change that you have to import the parent CA into Windows as well, and if the CA has a parent as well, import that too and so on, until you reach a CA that is self signed (it doesn't have parent, or it's its own parent), that one is called the **ROOT CA**.

The list of CAs starting with the ROOT CA and ending with your certificate is called a **certificate chain**. After you import the whole certificate chain, Windows will no longer complain, and in the "Certificate' window, selecting the "Certificate path" tab, you'll see the whole certificate chain in a tree-like structure starting with the ROOT CA, and ending with your certificate (which now it's the only one displayed there), where each certificate is listed under its parent.

Comment: No need to import all up the chain. One can stop at any point and simply grant that certificate authority.

Comment: Thank you for improvements.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful in understanding how it works.  But I can't ask my users to install a bunch of certificates (or, probably, to manually grant authority to one).  So, does Windows come with some approved certificates by default?  Where can I find a list of these?  Or, are Windows users already used to approving a new CA now and then?

Comment: The certificate authorities themselves will be able to tell you whether they can provide you with a code-signing certificate valid for Windows.  But you can also download a PDF from Microsoft with a list of root certificate program members.  [Search for "root certificate program".](https://www.microsoft.com/EN-US/search/result.aspx?q=root+certificate+program&form=apps).

Comment: I don't have a fresh install Windows at this point, but I imagine that there are some trusted CAs (whether they are inside the setup disks, or they come via updates) in the Cert store. On a machine that's being often operated, the Cert store is constantly updated, as some apps (or sites) require new certs. I imagine that on Mac it worked smoothly since the Apple CA, is installed by default (I've seen a bunch, on my Niresh Mac). Here's [Ms code sign intro site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx), which describes the certification process (that can be painful).